# Passing data from handler to HTML Templates Golang gin

Tags: go

is there an error in my code? here i am passing data users (slice of object) from handler to template, but when i want to try to display data in html, it is not showing

userHandler.go

```
func (h *userHandler) Index(c *gin.Context) {
    users, err := h.userService.GetAll()
    if err != nil {
        c.HTML(http.StatusInternalServerError, "error.html", nil)
        return
    }
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "user_index.html", gin.H{
        "users":    users,
        "testings": "testing string",
    })
    //Check data
    //fmt.Printf("%v", users)
}
```

user_index.html

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="table1">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> {{ .testings }}</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Ocuppation</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {{ range .users}}
                    <tr>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td>{{ .Name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ .Email }}</td>
                        <td>{{ .Ocuppation }}</td>
                        <td>
                        <span class="badge bg-success">Active</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {{ end }}
                    
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

routing

```
router.HTMLRender = loadTemplates("./web/templates")


router.GET("/users", userWebHandler.Index)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cq7D.png)

sorry for my lacking

data users can showing in html templates